# Limiting pdf size within an <object> element

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to display previews of pdfs through the  element and I'm wondering if there's a way to only display the first page of the pdf, rather than load the entire thing. If not, could I find a workaround using ?

Comment: i dont think so - you could read the file on your web server and use a pdf library to only serve the first pagge